# Teaching online when living outside america

Tags: tutoring, teachers

How can a high school maths teacher find opportunities to teach online?

This could be for students from any country.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about the job prospects of teaching mathematics, and not about math education, in general. This question is likely better suited for academia.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Teaching Math online is non-trivial.
1.  You need both some form of blackboard/whiteboard link that updates in near real time.  (Delay of no more than a second or two.)
2.  You need a good audio link for the students to hear you speak.

So far so good.

You need a way for a student to ask a question, so the audio link has to be selectable and two way.  You need a way for the student to indicate that she/he wants to ask a question.  This can be done with chat, but also really needs a way for the student to use a mouse on a particular point on the screen.

Generally you do not want the entire class to be able to edit the screen, although having kids do a problem on their own page then review, is a good way to do things.

3. Whiteboard should have provision for bringing in backgrounds.  Much easier to graph on a sheet of electronic graph paper.  Drawing on a grid is generally easier.

---

You need a reasonably fast link to your students.  Interactive whiteboards start to get clunky at delays of over 150 ms or so.  This is fairly easy to achieve on a single continent, but overseas doesn't work well.

You need to speak the same language as your students.  More than that, you need to speak with the same accent. Accent problems are not helped by the distortions introduced in digital links.  I have difficulty with English as spoken by most people from India.  I had a Chinese teaching assistant in calculus that was so bad that I stopped going to the help sessions.  Impossible accent and very limited vocabulary.

The way to advertise is on the internet.  Use the online classifieds such as craigslist, kijiji, backpage and place an ad in the services section.  I strongly recommend just doing one region at a time.  It will be far easier to teach if all your students are using the same textbook.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I have registered for an online course for virtual teaching: https://www.coursera.org/course/virtualinstruction. Just found it and excited.